# How to link to yaml-cpp on Arch Linux with qtcreator?

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator, archlinux, yaml-cpp

I'm interested in using Yaml in my media player project. The only problem is I can't figure out how you compile with Yaml, especially on qt-creator. The AUR package for yaml-cpp doesn't seem to install the libs in /usr/lib for some reason, so I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I'm using Qt and developing within the Qtcreator environment. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does it install the library?

Comment: Just grab the yaml-cpp source code and build it yourself using your prefered compiler. For Windows I built it using CMake and MinGW. Then I copied the libyaml-cpp.a file into my desired location and added it in .pro file. That's all

Comment: If using yaourt to install the package, you can try yaourt -Ql yaml-cpp to get the list of files for the package.

Answer (score 0):

I used QtCreator to start a CMake project, then used a CMake file to find yaml-cpp. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/attachmentText?id=127&aid=1270002000&name=FindYamlCpp.cmake&token=42ea076969957f49fef41ed1ca8790b4) is the CMake file to link yaml-cpp to your project.

Additionally, you should be able to go into your ".pro" file, r-click, and hit "add library". Select "system library", then you can use either pkgconfig or manual if you know where the lib is. If you can't figure out where it is, look in the PKGBUILD for yaml-cpp - it will tell you where it installs everything.